# Magento 1.9.2 custom admin grid redirects to 404 error page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to add order items grid in the sales section of the admin panel

I am following the below link for the same 
[How to Add a Custom Table to Magento Admin Backend](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/adding-custom-table-magento-admin-interface)

I am getting the menu as order items in sales => order items but when I click on the order items  Link to goes to 404 error page

following  is the code in my config.xml file

```
<config>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <order_items translate="title">
                    <title>Order Items</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/order_items/index</action>
                </order_items>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

I have added Ikantam_KnowledgeBase.xml file in app/etc/modules folder which contains the following code :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Ikantam_KnowledgeBase>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Ikantam_KnowledgeBase>
</modules>
```

i was not able to see the menu until I added this file in the above mentioned location . which was not given in the tutorial .

Now I am able to create the menu but the menu takes me to 404 error page.

The tutorial also mentions adding the following code in the configuration file

```
<config>   
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <knowledgebase before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ikantam_KnowledgeBase_Adminhtml</knowledgebase>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

when I added the above code to the config.xml files code the order items menu disappeared .

I am very new to Magento ,I  have no idea where this code should be added.
Any Help will be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Have you set ACL permissions for this? It's usually the cause of 404 errors

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis I am new to magento , I have no idea what ACL permissions are ,i have just followed the tutorial .

Answer (score 1):

You should set the ACL permissions for your new admin page
In you config.xml add the following. That is, put the whole  tag after your  tag

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
     ...
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <sales module="sales">
                            <children>
                                <order_items>
                                    <title>Order Items</title>
                                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                                </order_items>
                            </children>
                        </sales>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        ...
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

At this point I have to tell you that it is better to create a different adminhtml.xml file and put  and  tags in there.

If you want to add a router for your module then you must replace the module name in the given code. So it will be something like the following.

```
<admin>
<routers>
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <module_name before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml</module_name>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
</routers>
```

- '**module_name**' should be the router you have given to your module i.e.
  '**order_items**' and should match
  'adminhtml/**order_items**/index'
- 'Namespace_Modulename' should be replaced with your module's full name